# Where are the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) packages installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I know visual C++ 2015-2022 is installed because:

A. I see it in Apps & Features (Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.31.31103
B. I see it in registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\X64

but %VCINSTALLDIR% is not set on my path, and I cant find the dll's anywhere.

I need to be really specific with my IT dept to get this fixed. I want to add the dll to the system path but I have to find them first!

I managed to find `VC_redist.x64.exe` in `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2aaf1df0-eb13-4099-9992-962bb4e596d1}` but I think that is pretty strange... it may be unrelated to the install.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It will be set in a Visual Studio Command prompt. I have my windows terminal with links to the VS Command prompt for each completely separate build tree I work on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me they are at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC
```

Do note that `%VCINSTALLDIR%` only works in the [Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022).  That should be located under the Visual Studio XXXX folder in your start menu or it can be launched directly from inside visual studio.  You can then enter

```
cd %VCINSTALLDIR%
```

in the terminal to get where the directory is located on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the developer command prompt. Is it weird that I see it installed but I don't see Microsoft Visual Studio anywhere in program files? (x64 or x86)

Comment: @Frank Are you saying you have MSVS installed on your machine, but there is no folder for it under the program files folders?  If so, `cd %VCINSTALLDIR%` from the developer terminal will tell you where MSVS is installed at.

Comment: I have MS Visual C++ Redistributable installed, verified in registry, with no folder in program files. Also no visual studio in start menu and no developer terminal anywhere.

Comment: @Frank Ah, okay.  Looks like you found it then in `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2aaf1df0-eb13-4099-9992-962bb4e596d1}`.  My folder only contains 4 executables: vc_redist.x64.exe, vc_redist.x86.exe, vcredist.x64.exe, vcredist.x86.exe.  The actual DLLs are most likely going to be in WinSxS folder.

Comment: @Frank I believe it is `msvcrt.dll` that you are looking for and that should be in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` or in one of the WinSxS subfolders

Comment: but it is broken and if I click it it asks me to repair, but it fails to repair per group policy. Why is it broken in the first place? And why would it be in program cache but nothing under program files?

Comment: @Frank the redistributables only install the DLLs that are required to run applications compiled with visual studio, they don't install any part of visual studio itself. The DLLs are installed in the windows system directories so you wont see anything in program files. If you want to build things you need to install the VS build tools instead

Comment: @Frank It's  not that weird.  While it is listed under add and remove programs, it really isn't a program.  It's a collection of DLL's that other programs interact with.

Comment: Thanks, if I double click ```VC_redist.x64.exe ``` should it open though? Because when I click that, it it gives two options: repair or uninstall

Comment: Ohhhh wait, when I try to repair it says "This program is blocked by group policy" maybe that is my problem!

Comment: @Frank That's all you get.  There is nothing to "open".  Those exe's just "install" the needed DLL's into the appropriate system locations so that programs built using MSVS features can use them without included all of the code in their in own program.

Comment: @Frank: `VC_redist.x64.exe` is supposed to be run by installers, not manually. You would download "SetupFooApp.EXE", which would copy Foo App to `Program Files` and then run `VC_redist.x64.exe` for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Github/Microsoft](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/main/docs/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files.md) Visual C++ Files are in `%VCINSTALLDIR%Redist\MSVC\v143` folder.

> The easiest way to locate the redistributable files is by using environment variables set in a developer command prompt. In Visual Studio 2022, the redistributable files are in the **%VCINSTALLDIR%Redist\MSVC\v143** folder. In the latest version of Visual Studio 2019, you'll find the redistributable files in the **%VCINSTALLDIR%Redist\MSVC\v142** folder. In both Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019, they're also found in %VCToolsRedistDir%. In Visual Studio 2015, these files can be found in %VCINSTALLDIR%redist<locale>, where  is the locale of the redistributable packages.

Answer (score 0):

> I know visual C++ 2015-2022 is installed because:
>
> A. I see it in Apps & Features (Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022
> Redistributable (x64) - 14.31.31103
> ...

You're confusing Visual Studio (the development environment) with Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (a runtime support library). There isn't even such a thing as "visual C++ 2015-2022". Each version of Visual Studio has one specific year, such as Visual Studio 2017 (VS2017). The redistributable works for all Visual Studio versions between VS2015 and VS2022.

`%VCINSTALLDIR%` is set by the command prompts of **all** Visual Studio version, but the value will differ **between** Visual Studio variants. You can install multiple versions of Visual Studio side by side on the same computer.